# where does jetty serve files from

Tags: jetty-9

I just installed jetty 9.4.6.  I dropped one of the war files from the demo area into $JETTY_BASE/webapps.  The war file got expanded into /tmp/jetty-10.1.100.103-8080-test.war-_test-any-4774924669679182185.dir

I then tried a curl on it like this: :8080/test/index.html.  I get a 503 error.  I verified that index.html exists.

So does jetty serve the compressed war file or does it serve from the tmp folder?  Any doc links would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it creates a temp directory, though you can also define and persist your own if you'd like.

> By default, Jetty will create this directory inside the directory
>   named by the java.io.tmpdir System property. You can instruct Jetty to
>   use a different parent directory by setting the context attribute
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.basetempdir to the name of the desired parent
>   directory. The directory named by this attribute must exist and be
>   writeable.

You can find more in the [official documentation here](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/ref-temporary-directories.html).